# creating constants in a for loop as you can with define()

Tags: php, constants

Right now the code base that I'm working with does stuff like this in the constructor:

```
$constants = array('CONSTANT1' => 1, 'CONSTANT2' => 2);
foreach ($constants as $name=>$val) {
    if (!defined($name) {
        define($name, $val);
    }
}
```

I would like to do this with PHP5 const's instead. ie. so instead of in the code doing `if ($var == CONSTANT1)` I could do `if ($var == self::CONSTANT1)`.

Any idea how I might do this?

Comment: i guess you should shed some light on the case where you've needed this, because it looks as a strange case to me (also, nothing but eval/files created on-the-fly, probably on vfs, will save you).

Comment: It's a several MB big proprietary code base and even if I were able to show it to you I doubt you'd spend the time to go through it when you're not being paid to do so. If you're asking because you're wondering if the "dynamic" define's could be made static...  probably. But if that's the route I take I don't really have any questions that merit a post on SO. The question I have asked is my attempt to ascertain the feasibility of an arguably easier approach.

Comment: in that case i'd stick to virtual filesystem and dynamically created files (it's *a little bit* safer than plain eval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i would like to do this with PHP5 const's instead.

To the best of my knowledge, you can not add [class constants](http://php.net/language.oop5.constants) at runtime in PHP without the runkit extension.

With the runkit extension however you can to it similar as with `define`: [`runkit_constant_add`](http://php.net/runkit-constant-add).

```
runkit_constant_add(sprintf('%s::%s', get_class($this), $name), $val);
```

As the runkit extension is pretty internal, this is a strong sign that you've got an issue with the design.

If you can live with variables, you could consider to opt for static global class variables.

So as you've explicitly asked for it: Yes, install (and help maintaining) the  [runkit extension](http://php.net/runkit).